# Google search console reports redirects from my preferred www setting (Canonicalization seems to be working backwards?)

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, canonical-url

I have two variations of my domain on webmasters. One is http://**www** and the other is non-www.

I have set my preferred domain to be non-www.

I have used the function "Fetch as Google" and have had redirects in both of them.

Firstly, my **http**://**www** redirects to **https**

Secondly, my non-www redirects to www (http not https)

My questions are:
- Should I be adding a variation of my site to webmasters as **https** as well? Is there a way to canonicalize http vs https?
- Are these re-directs a problem?
- Does it sound like I have duplicate content from what you can see?
- Why is my non-www redirecting to my www when I have set the canonicalization to non-www preferred?

Comment: If you visit your site in your browser with no-www, do you get a redirect?

Comment: Yes, if I type non-www it goes to https://www although I have setn canonical to non-www.

Should I perhaps set my canonical to www seeing as this is what it is doing anyway?

Comment: If you have redirects in place from one to the other, there is no need to set the preferred one in Google Search Console.   You shouldn't set your preferred one to one that redirects.

Comment: I don't want it to redirect, but it's just happeneing. Through further research it may be because I have used Wix (yes, I know, working on coding it myself but it's okay for now) and apparently Wix automatically pushes the site to a www regardless of how I have set my canonical. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll consider my questions answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess, you should have some troubles with settings of http, https, www and non-www on the hoster side (or in your htaccess, httpd.conf or nginx.conf - don't know, what webserver in use).

- Inspect your setup - what variant redirect where.
- After inspection establish only one canonical variant, like https://www,
- than make sure, that every other variant is 301-redirected to the canonical.
- Than setup your Search console according to your canonical variant.